# How to redirect the user to dashboard if i remove the "/dashboard" from the port server in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, dashboard

My port server is my login interface. * http://127.0.0.1:8000/* That is my login part, after entering my details it will redirect me to my dashboard *http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard*. But if I remove the */dashboard* from the *url* it returns me back to login even when I am still in session and hasn't yet click the logout button. If I put the */dashboard* again I will return to the dashboard because the user is still in session. I want to return to dashboard even I remove */dashboard*. How to do that in Laravel?

Comment: you can handle it with middleware to check. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#introduction

Comment: add your routes in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Middleware can do this work for you. just follow

1. Firstly, you have to create a middleware.

```
php artisan make:middleware RedirectIfUserAuthenticated
```

2. Register your middleware at kernel:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ..............................
    'auth.backend' => Middleware\RedirectIfUserAuthenticated::class,
 ];
```

3. Call your middleware at your routes or controller which you want to user authenticated can see after they're login.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.backend'], function () {
     // Add your routes except login route.
}]);
```

4. Let's added some codes into middleware that we have created: `RedirectIfUserAuthenticated`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfUserAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

- Important: You can added middlware `auth` to your routes this will work as well if you don't want to create new one:
  Locat at: Middlewares/Authenticat.php and custom whatever your want.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], function () {
     // Add your routes except login route.
}]);
```

Done !

Comment: Thank you. I will do this one. Sorry I am new in Laravel.

Comment: You're welcome @Luffy

Comment: I will reply here after I tried it out.

Answer (score 1):

In your RouteServiceProvider, is HOME set to '/dashboard'?

```
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```

Comment: Yes I want to redirect when I'm still login.

Comment: I have tried it. But still the same, it still goes back to my login route.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `guest` middleware to your `/` route or any route you want an "authenticated" user to be sent to the "dashboard" instead:

```
Route::get('/', ...)->middleware('guest');
```

Depending on the version this will already redirect any authenticated user to `/dashboard`.